# Xamarin.UITest: How to Retrieve All Elements in List

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I have a list of 500 elements and when I use `app.Query` on the page, Xamarin.UITest gives me only 6 elements as only 6 elements are visible in UI.

How can I retrieve all 500 elements from the list inside of my UITest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described above, the expected behavior of `app.Query` will only return the results of all visible controls on the page. Thus, if a control is not visible, `app.Query` will not return it.

The way to retrieve all of the data in a list is to use a Backdoor Method.

Xamarin has [additional documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-backdoors/?WT.mc_id=none-github-bramin) on how to use backdoors in UITest.

## Sample App

This sample app implements the snippets from the tutorial:
https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp

## Tutorial

### 1. Create a Serializable Object

Because Backdoor Methods are limited to return a string, we will need to be able to serialize our object.

You will need to add the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) NuGet package to each of your projects; i.e. add the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet to the .NET Standard project, the iOS Project, the Android Project and the UITest Project.

### 2. Create Static Methods to Serialize the Object

These methods will be used to serialize and deserialize the object.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class ConverterHelpers
{
    public static string SerializeObject(object value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

### 3. Add Backdoor Method to AppDelegate

This method in the `AppDelegate` will expose a backdoor from your iOS app that the UITest can utilize.

If you do not have an iOS app, skip this step.

```cs
[Export("getDataAsString:")]
public NSString GetDataAsString(NSString noValue)
{
    var data = [Add code here to retrieve the data from your app]

    var dataAsString = ConverterHelpers.SerializeObject(data);

    return new NSString(dataAsString);
}
```

### 4. Add Backdoor Method to MainActivity or Application class

This method in the `MainActivity` (or the `Application` class, if you have one) will expose a backdoor from your Android app that the UITest can utilize.

If you do not have an Android app, skip this step.

```cs
[Export("GetDataAsString")]
public string GetDataAsString()
{
    var data = [Add code here to retrieve the data from your app]

    var dataAsBase64String = ConverterHelpers.SerializeObject(data);

    return dataAsBase64String;
}
```

### 5. Create Static Method to Invoke Backdoors from UITest

Create a static method in the UITest project to invoke backdoor methods from UITest.

```cs
internal static List<DataModel> GetListData(IApp app)
{
    string dataAsString;

    if (app is iOSApp)
        dataAsString = app.Invoke("getDataAsString:", "").ToString();
    else
        dataAsString = app.Invoke("GetDataAsString").ToString();

    return ConverterHelpers.DeserializeObject<List<DataModel>>(dataAsString);
}
```

### 6. Invoke the Backdoor From The UITest

In the UITest test method, implement the static method to retrieve the data.

```cs
[Test]
public void VerifyData()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(GetListData(app).Count == 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still asking this question, there is now an [AppQuery.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.queries.appquery.all?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk#Xamarin_UITest_Queries_AppQuery_All_System_String_) which changes the query to return all elements instead of just the visible ones.

Comment: I've only tried on Android, but I've never got `All()` to work for me - it only returns the *visible* elements, but duplicated. Does it actually work for you?