# How to get count of the listview items at Xamarin UITests

Tags: listview, xamarin, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

Suppose I have Xamarin application and page that show list of specific items.
I want to write UI test that will add some items and than try to count them.

I have next listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
              BackgroundColor="Transparent" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false" Margin="20, 0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid AutomationId="ListItem" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="38" Grid.Row="1">
                                <!-- item's description -->
                            </StackLayout>          
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And my UI test:

```
[Test]
    public void CheckForSamplesAdding()
    {
        app.Tap(c => c.Id("PageWithList"));

        // add some items: 

        app.EnterText("inputForItem", "item001");
        app.PressEnter();

        Task.Delay(250);

        app.EnterText("inputForItem", "item002");
        app.PressEnter();

        Task.Delay(250);

        app.EnterText("inputForItem", "item003");
        app.PressEnter();

        Task.Delay(250);

        // assert to check count of listView items
    }
```

I think I have to add automationId to the listview and somehow describe checking of count of items in this listview.. But I can't find any information how to perform it..
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to count the number of elements displayed on screen with something like that :

```
app.Query(x => x.Marked("ListView").Child()).Length
```

if you want to count all the elements you should use a [backdoor](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/) like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401601/5359812).

An other solution could be to scroll to try to find the element in the list (useful if you want to test more than just the element creation).